# How can I copy values from one dataframe to other dataframe fastly

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to create on my Dataframe (Global_Dataset) a new column (Col_val) based on the other Dataframe (List_Data).
I need a **faster** code because I have a dataset of 2 million samples and List_data contains 50000 samples.

**Col_Val** must contain the value of column **Value** according to **Col_Key**

**List_Data:**

```
id     Key     Value
1       5        0
2       7        1
3       9        2
```

**Global_Dataset:**

```
id    Col_Key     Col_Val
1        9           2
2        5           0
3        9           2 
4        7           1
5        7           1
6        5           0
7        9           2
8        7           1
9        9           2
10       5           0
```

I have tried this code but it needs a long time to be executed. Is there any other **faster** way for achieving my goal?

```
Col_Val = []
for i in range (len(List_Data)):
    for j in range (len(Global_Data)):
        if List_Data.get_value(i, "Key") == Global_Data.get_value(j, 'Col_Key') :
            Col_Val.append(List_Data.get_value(i, 'Value'))

Global_Data['Col_Val'] = Col_Val
```

**PS: I have tried loc and iloc instead of get_value but it works very slow**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data_dict = {key : value for key, value in zip(List_Data['Key'], List_Data['Value'])}
Global_Data['Col_Val'] = pd.Series([data_dict[key] for key in Global_Data['Col_Key']])
```

I don't know how long it will takes on your machine with the amount of data you need to handle, but it should be faster of what you are using now.
You could also generate the dictionary with `data_dict = {row['Key'] : row['Value'] for _, row in list_data.iterrows()}` but on my machine is slower than what I proposed above.

It works under the assumption that all the keys in `Global_Data['Col_Keys']` are present in `List_Data['Key']`, otherwise you will get a `KeyError`.

Comment: +1 from me, you beat my answer by about 6x time to run! `2.94 ms` for me, `565 µs` for you on the provided data

Comment: thank you Valentino both of them are very faster than my code

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to loop through anything, either manually or with `iterrows`. If I understand your problem, this should be a simple [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operation.

```
df
    Key Value
id      
1   5   0
2   7   1
3   9   2

global_df
    Col_Key
   id   
1   9
2   5
3   9
4   7
5   7
6   5
7   9
8   7
9   9
10  5

global_df.reset_index()\
.merge(df, left_on='Col_Key', right_on='Key')\
.drop('Key', axis=1)\
.set_index('id')\
.sort_index()

    Col_Key Value
id      
1   9   2
2   5   0
3   9   2
4   7   1
5   7   1
6   5   0
7   9   2
8   7   1
9   9   2
10  5   0
```

Note that the essence of this is the `global_df.merge(...)`, but the extra operations are to keep the original indexing and remove unwanted extra columns. I encourage you to try each step individually to see the results.